# Printing every value from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3

This is how I am storing contact details in my Adressbook app.. I'm doing filter so I need to print every position value but if there is same position twice or more then just print it only once..

So for example If I have 3 contacts with positions : Web Developer, Economy, Web Developer, it will print only Web Developer and Economy.

How can I do that? Trying it for a while without success. But print only position which `userEmail == $0.addedByUser`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Follow below this code,

```
    let rootRef:FIRDatabaseReference! = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let userDataRef =  rootRef.child("contacts").child("User Email--\(id)")]
        userDataRef!.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in

            if(snapshot.value != nil){

    if let addedByuser = (snapshot.value  as? [String : Any])? ["addedByUser"]{
        print("Added by user>> \(addedByuser)")
    }
  }

        }){ (error) in
           dPrint("error ChildAdded \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
```